# How to break struct members into bytes of a single word

Tags: c, structure

Say I have a C structure like:

```
typedef struct {
UINT8  nRow;
UINT8  nCol;
UINT16 nData; } tempStruct;
```

Is there a way to put all of those 3 members of the struct into a single 32-bit word, yet still be able to access them individually?

Comment: Yes, but isn't it just convenient to let the compiler do that for you (which it probably does, assuming your `UINT*` types have sane definitions)?

Comment: You could use a `union`, but you should make sure there is no padding in the `struct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just referring to it as a UINT32? It's not like C is type-safe.

```
tempStruct t;
t.nRow = 0x01;
t.nCol = 0x02;
t.nData = 0x04;

//put a reference to the struct as a pointer to a UINT32
UINT32* word = (UINT32 *) &t;

printf("%x", *word);
```

You can then get the value of the struct as a 32-bit word by dereferencing the pointer. The specifics of your system may matter, though...if I run this on my machine, the value of `word` is 0x00040201---that is, the fields are in reverse order. I don't think that's necessarily going to be the case if you're trying to serialize this to another system, so it's not portable.

If you want to actually store it as a 32-bit integer and then refer to the fields individually, why not

```
UINT32 word = 0x01020004;
```

and then somewhere else...

```
UINT8* row(UINT32 word) {
    return (UINT8 *) &word + 3;
}

UINT8* col(UINT32 word) {
    return ((UINT8 *) &word) + 2;
}

UINT16* data(UINT32 word) {
    return ((UINT16 *) &word);
}
```

Macros will facilitate portable endianness.

Comment: This appears to be a workable solution, it compiles correctly with my existing code at least.

Answer (score 3):

Something with the help of `union`s?

```
typedef struct {
 UINT8  nRow;
 UINT8  nCol;
 UINT16 nData; 
} 
tempStruct;

typedef union {
 tempStruct myStruct;
 UINT32 myWord;
} stuff;
```

Or even better (with no "intermediate" struct):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    struct {
        int  nRow:8;
        int  nCol:8;
        int nData:16;
    }; 
    int myWord;
} stuff;

int main(int args, char** argv){
    stuff a;
    a.myWord=0;
    a.nCol=2;
    printf("%d\n", a.myWord);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for a UNION here.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz, I thought the OP wants to be able to retrieve the whole 32 bits within the struct. Not sure though...

Comment: Also, if `tempStruct` has padding due to the compiler chosing to lay the struct out that way, stuffing it into a union won't change that. The entire union will just be bigger, then...

Comment: I actually want to be able to write to all 32 bits at a time.  I have the Row/Col/Intensity in a 32 bit word that I want to write to the structure and have it populate the fields appropriately.

Comment: In which format are the *original* 32 bits you want to write at a time? Where do they come from? Are they continuously in memory, or are they in different places?

Comment: I want to define my structure in the same way as the 32-bit data.  They're in memory.  So bits 31:24 would be nRow, bits 23:16 would be nCol, bits 15:0 would be nData.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [**bit fields**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) in C to do that. Something like:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned nRow : 8;
  unsigned nCol : 8;
  unsigned nData : 16;
} tempStruct;
```

If you want to control the memory layout also, you might want to take a look at [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). A non-portable option available on some compilers for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
 int  nRow:8;
 int  nCol:8;
 int nData:16; } tempStruct;
```

nRow will take only 8 bit and nCol will take 8 bit and nDate will take 16bit.

This will work for you.

I just wrote sample program to see the size of it

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct {
     int  nRow:8;
     int  nCol:8;
     int nData:16; } tempStruct;

typedef struct {
     int  nRow;
     int  nCol;
     int nData; } tempStructZ;

int main(void) {
      printf("%d\n", sizeof(tempStruct));
      printf("%d\n", sizeof(tempStructZ));
      return 0;
}
```

Output:
4
16

Comment: What I am trying to do is populate all 32 bits inside tempStruct with a single 32-bit write, and have it populate the members of the structure appropriately.  I get compile errors with your solution when i do int nRow:8, etc.

Comment: The compile error occurs when I'm trying to send a pointer to the structure to another function that expects to populate its 32-bit word.  The code you write compiles fine.

Comment: Good to know that :). Can you share your test code so that we can look in to it.